# How to implement EF Core abstract based model with navigation properties of abstract types

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I am trying to implement common DDD-based entity using Entity Framework Core.
I have 2 separated databases, external and internal, which shares common table models and logic in some places.
Ive tried to implement it that way:

```
public abstract class EmployeeBase
{
  public Guid Id {get;}
  public string Name {get; protected set;}
  public Guid DepartmentId {get; protected set;}

  public DeparmentBase {get; protected set;}

  public void DomainMethod1() {...}
  public void DomainMethod2() {...}
}
```

```
public class InternalEmployee : EmployeeBase
{
}
```

```
public class ExternalEmployee : EmployeeBase
{
}
```

```
public abstract class DepartmentBase
{
  public Guid Id {get;}
  public string Name {get; protected set;}

  public ICollection<EmployeeBase> Employees {get; protected set;}

  public void DomainMethod1() {...}
  public void DomainMethod2() {...}
}
```

```
public class InternalDepartment : DepartmentBase
{
}
```

```
public class ExternalDepartment : DepartmentBase
{
}
```

Is it even possible to to that in entity framework core? I can not find the way to configure it using FluentAPI. Can anyone help?
I am also not sure if it is a good idea to implement domain logic in abstract classes with  nested properties of abstract type as well. Is there any better alternative?
Thank you in advance!ent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible to to that in entity framework core?

Yes it is, documentation is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

> I am also not sure if it is a good idea to implement domain logic in abstract classes with nested properties of abstract type as well. Is there any better alternative?

**You are confusing DDD entities (domain model) with EF entities (persistence model).**

Implementing domain logic in an abstract class with nested abstract properties is not a problem. What is a problem is doing that in an EF model, as it puts lots of stress on the object-relational mapping, especially if you have two back-end databases.

What an ORM (such as EF core) does is translating operations on objects into the relational world, and vice-versa. They usually manipulate POCO objects with as few logic as possible inside, because they are symbols: they *represent*, in the object world, database concepts, such as tables, rows, columns, indexes, etc ...

You can use the same business-persistence model if your application is designed with a *domain-first* approach. In that situation, the ORM is only responsible to persist the domain state *as-is* and the database structure follows *by design* the domain model. However, this model can become very complex, because it must both model the business logic *and* respect database design good practices. It only works if your business model is trivial.

Here, you have constraints on your database structure (two databases) and a complex domain model (with abstract/polymorphism), so you are not free to use your persistence layer a simple "save my domain state" library. You should split your concerns into different models:

- One persistence model per database, with anemic POCO and no abstract classes or properties
- One domain model with abstract classes and properties, implementing your domain logic

You may then implement an adapter between the models, with a repository pattern:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core